# How to populate a property with data from another property at load

Tags: c#, properties

I have a `virtual Property SomeList` of type `ICollection<X>` and a `Property SomeNarrowList` of type `ICollection<Y>`.

`Class X` contains a `virtual property Element` of `Class Y`.

`SomeList` is being populated from a database after which a few methods are used to retrieve specific data from the `Element`.

As I'm doing things right now, whenever a method like this is called, a check is performed to see if `SomeNarrowList` is empty and if so, fill it with the `Element` properties of `SomeList`.

This code seems rather messy to me, and I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

My first thought was providing an implementation for the `get` value of the `SomeNarrowList` property, but this raised the question: in what order - if any - are properties loaded when they're mapped using EF? If the `SomeNarrowList` property would be loaded before `SomeList`, this would result in an empty `SomeNarrowList`.

Another thought would be the use of LINQ to always refer to the `SomeList` property and take every `Element` property from there, but I haven't quite figured out yet how to do this.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is as you said using a LINQ query in the getter of property, like this:

```
public ICollection<Y> SomeNarrowList
{
    get { return SomeList.Select(p => p.Element).ToList(); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems like I was looking for `Select`! I've gone with my second thought to avoid having to define a set property and subsequently add another variable to my class.